# How do i get a third party library to build automatically using gradle build scripts?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

i want to build jansson c library automatically. How do i tell gradle to do that automatically.

Usually manual commands are necessary to compile and install third party native libraries. Is it possible to compile and install it automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jansson has CMakeLists.txt; configure your app/build.gradle to build your native code.

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {...}
  buildTypes {...}

  // Encapsulates your external native build configurations.
  externalNativeBuild {

    // Encapsulates your CMake build configurations.
    cmake {

      // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
      path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
  }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds.html#configure-gradle

Comment: It says "module-level build.gradle" , is it app level  app/build.gradle ?

Comment: 'app' is one of the module for this project.

Comment: its throwing a bunch of error, saying Build command failed.. Is there any alternatives

Comment: This is the right way of handling native code. We need to fix those errors.

Comment: So this library has to be build and compiled before the app can be run. Some of the frameworks in the c code uses jansson_private_config.h , however that is not in the jannson library when u run the app. If i manually paste that file into jannson library, its working.

Comment: It is when u run ./configure
make
make check
make install , we get  jansson_private_config.h  in jansson library folders

Comment: I see that 'CMakeLists.txt has '# configure the private config file
configure_file (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/jansson_private_config.h.cmake
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/private_include/jansson_private_config.h)'. This will ensure that header file is copied.

Comment: are you saying, i have to change the CMakeLists.txt  file ?

Comment: I am saying that CMakeLists.txt is taking care of copying that header file as part of build. Just plug that CMakeLists.txt to app/build.gradle